# Find confidence interval for negative binomial using Mathematica

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I would like to find the exact 95% confidence intervals on the mean of a negative binomial random variable using Mathematica. It is possible to approximate the distribution using a gamma/normal, but not for parameter ranges in which I am interested. As such, I would like a way of numerically deriving the 95% confidence intervals

The way in which Mathematica defines the negative binomial distribution, is in terms of $n$ and $p$, and the mean can be calculated as:

```
Mean[NegativeBinomialDistribution[n, p]]
```

which returns $\frac{n(1-p)}{p}$. It is this estimated quantity which I would like to construct confidence intervals around.

Does anyone have an idea as to how to start here? I must admit I am a bit stuck as to where to start.

Best,

Ben

Comment: You need to be a bit clearer about your purpose. Do you need the interval within which 95% of the `m` variates drawn from `NegativeBinomialDistribution[n, p]` fall? Or do you want the CI around the *measured* mean describing the 95% probability of the position of their real mean?

Comment: I want a 95% confidence interval around the estimated mean. Does that make sense? I have edited the question now to reflect this. Best, Ben

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The distribution of the means of sufficiently large sets of random drawings from a given distribution (well, many of them) approaches a normal distribution with a mean equal to the mean of the given distribution and a standard deviation equal to the standard deviation of the given distribution divided by the square root of the sample size -1.

Using this information, you obtain the theoretical bounds using `Quantile`:

```
Block[{sampleSize = 100, p = 0.1, lb = 0.025, ub = 0.975, mean},
  mean = Mean[NegativeBinomialDistribution[sampleSize, p]];
  Quantile[
     NormalDistribution[
       mean, 
       StandardDeviation[NegativeBinomialDistribution[sampleSize, p]]/
       Sqrt[sampleSize - 1]
     ], 
     {lb, ub}
   ]
]

(* {881.312, 918.688} *)
```

A simulation:

```
Block[{sampleSize = 100, p = 0.1, simSampleSize = 1000000, lb = 0.025, ub = 0.975},
   Quantile[
     Mean /@ 
     RandomVariate[
       NegativeBinomialDistribution[sampleSize,p], 
       {simSampleSize, sampleSize}
     ]//N, 
    {lb, ub}
   ]
 ]
(* {881.47, 918.7} *)
```

---

**Update: Exact approach**

For low values of the sample size the normal distribution approximation doesn't hold. One can obtain the numerical exact (but unfortunately not parametrizable) result as follows:

```
Block[{sampleSize = 5, n = 9, p = 0.1, lb = 0.025, ub = 0.975},
  Quantile[
     TransformedDistribution[
        Total[Table[x[i], {i, sampleSize}]],
        Thread[
           Table[x[i], {i, sampleSize}] \[Distributed] 
           NegativeBinomialDistribution[n, p]
        ]
     ], {lb, ub}
    ]/sampleSize
  ] // N

(* {57.8, 107.6} *)
```

Note the division by `sampleSize` after the `Quantile` function. This is done because `Quantile` can handle  the `Total` of the random variables, but not the `Mean` or `Total[...]/sampleSize`. The result of ranking the means should be the same as the ranking of totals followed by a division by a constant.

Compare with simulation:

```
Block[{sampleSize = 5, n = 9, p = 0.1, simSampleSize = 100000, lb = 0.025, ub = 0.975},
 Quantile[
      Mean /@ 
      RandomVariate[
          NegativeBinomialDistribution[n, p], 
          {simSampleSize, sampleSize}
      ] // N, 
   {lb, ub}]
 ]

(* {57.8, 107.4} *)
```

**How it works:**

What I'm doing is to define a distribution that is the sum of `sampleSize` stochastic variables each distributed as a `NegativeBinomialDistribution`. This mimics the sample process that you perform if you draw from this distribution. This transformed distribution too has a `PDF`, `CDF`, `InverseCDF` and because of the latter also a `Quantile` function. Mathematica is able to calculate this function and so I can find the 2.5 and 97.5 percentile levels which define the 95% confidence interval. As I explained above, I used the `Total` with a division later on instead of the `Mean` directly as Mathematica doesn't seem to handle that in this case.

---

**Necessity of exact approach**

To show under which conditions the normal distribution approach would be sufficient we can generate a few plots using various levels of n, p and sample size. Note the erratic behavior of the exact predictions that match the simulations very well. Not so for the normal distribution approach for low sample sizes. The rule of thumb that one can use the approximation for sample sizes of 30 and up is confirmed.

```
ParallelTable[
  With[{
    l1 = If[n == 64, 
      PlotLegends -> PointLegend[{"Normal approach"}], {}],
    l2 = If[n == 64, PlotLegends -> PointLegend[{"Exact"}], {}],
    l3 = If[n == 64, PlotLegends -> PointLegend[{"Simulation"}], {}]},
   sims = 
    Table[Prepend[simulate[sampleSize, n, p, 100000, 0.025, 0.975], 
      sampleSize], {sampleSize, {3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34}}];
   Show[
    DiscretePlot[
     normalApp[sampleSize, n, p, 100000, 0.025, 0.975], {sampleSize, 
      3, 35}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Blue}, Filling -> None, 
     Joined -> True, l1],
    DiscretePlot[
     exactApp[sampleSize, n, p, 100000, 0.025, 0.975], {sampleSize, 3,
       35}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Darker@Green}, Filling -> None, 
     Joined -> True, l2],
    ListPlot[{sims[[All, {1, 2}]], sims[[All, {1, 3}]]}, 
     PlotStyle -> Red, l3]
    , Frame -> True, Axes -> None, 
    FrameLabel -> {If[p == 0.95, "Sample size", None], 
      If[n == 2, "2.5 / 97.5 percentile", None], 
      StringTemplate["n = ``. p =``"][n, p], ""}, ImageSize -> 250
    ]
   ], {p, {0.1, 0.5, 0.8, 0.95}}, {n, {2, 8, 64}}
  ] // Grid
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for your answer - much appreciated. I will use this for now, however, as a matter of interest, is there a way to derive the confidence intervals analytically? (By analytically, I mean rather than simulation). That's the only reason I am keeping the question open, if not, I will close it. Best, Ben

Comment: Just take out the Quantile block from the first block of code and evaluate that. It will give you the analytic result.

Comment: Thanks. I realise that, but this is using the normal approximation, which I said in the question, is not appropriate for my parameter range. Does that make sense? Best, Ben

Comment: @ben see update

Comment: If I could vote you more up, I would! Many thanks again! Best, Ben

Comment: @ben18785 tiny update: separated sample size and the parameter `n`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I really appreciate it. Can I just ask for direction towards a paper that explains what you have done? Alternatively, if you have time, it would be great to understand exactly how the above works? Best, Ben

Comment: @ben Sorry, no paper refs, but it's actually not that complex. I added a bit of explanation above.

Comment: Thanks again - much appreciated!

Comment: @ben18785 And one final update...

Comment: Nice illustration of the goodness of fit for the normal approximation. Thanks again! Best, Ben